# A stored procedure can not find a function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

here is parts of my stored procedure that can not find the function:

```
(dbo.fn_Get_Order_Contacts_Info_Full_Name(@order_detail_ID, 'Borrower')) As 'Borrower_Contact_Info_Full',   

replace(dbo.fn_get_business_product_element_requirements(t_order_detail.order_detail_id,288)
```

the functions exist in a scalar function as following:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Get_Order_Contacts_Info_Full_Name] 
(  

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_get_business_product_element_requirements] 
(
```

is there a reason why the proceedure can not find the scalar functions.

my error:

> can not find column "dbo" or the user defined function or aggregate " the 2 functions above", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: You may have to show more of/the entire query in which those calls exist.

Comment: Are the columns named exactly the same as how they are written in the database? Try just pulling the names from the side of SQL Server into the query instead of typing them out and see if that helps. I have had issues when I couldn't figure out what was wrong, then I just dragged and dropped the names and it worked fine. Weird bugs like that drive me nuts!

Comment: Sounds like you may not be using the right database. Try adding USING your_database_name in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I fixed this issue was with a closure of SQL and restart of the server and it worked.  Seems to be a bug in sql server.

Comment: I doubt that very much. Where did you see these errors? If it was intellisense you probably neeeded to refresh the cache.

Comment: A wrong database might be in use at the time. After restarting the server either the default DB was selected or you were careful enough to select the right one manually.

Comment: found the answer here [link] http://ycsoftware.net/cannot-find-either-column-dbo-or-the-name-is-ambiguous/[/link]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit harder to tell without seeing the whole query but here are things to look at:

- Are the functions in the database(s) you are refering to in the query?
- Did you accidentally create them in two databases, both of which are
  referenced in the query?
- Are you positive you have typed the names correctly and that they are
  in dbo?
- Are you sure those are scalar functions?
- Have you refreshed the database?